# How to create related database entries in Backand?

Tags: mysql, database, ionic-framework, backand

I am currently using Backand with the Ionic Framework.

In my model I have table A, which is connected to table B through a one to many relationship (A contains the object field, and B the collection field).

What is the proper way to create a related entry in table B?

What I am currently doing is this, but it somehow feels like a dirty hack:

1. I create a new object in table B, and set the collection field to the ID of the entry in table A.
2. I update the entry in table A, by placing the ID of the newly created B-entry in the object field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672602/adding-related-data-to-backand-api/38377843#38377843